# Know all baseclass's implementations

Tags: python, design-patterns

## Problem:

I am trying to simulate a boids particle system with python for an addon I am creating for Blender 3D, something quite complex and will be done from scratch.

Its the third time I try to design a maintainable code structure for it.

I tried to come up with pythonic design that allow for fast prototyping of different classes of particles interacting with each other, such that I can just create a new particle implementation and have it to interact with the other particles in the system.

see the example:

```
class ParticleSystem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.particles = []
    
    def add_particle(self, particle):
        self.particles.append(particle)
    
    def step_frame(self, speed):
        for p in self.particles:
            p.step(speed)
 
 
 class Particle:
    def __init__(self, system)
        self.location = Vector(0,0,0)
        self.system = system
    
    def step(speed):
        for particle in self.system.particles:
            #random interatcion formula
            self.location = particle.location + self.location

            
system = ParticleSystem()

p = Particle(system)
system.add_particle(p)
```

As you can see this my best aproach but it gets quite messy when I have multiple classes of particles and I have to pass the system to the particle and then the particle to the system.

## question

Is there a way so I can detect when the creation of a class implementation like: `Class Baseball(Particle):` and have the system class to know all the existing types so I can just call `system.create_baseball(location)`?

Comment: I can think of at least three reasonable and fairly unrelated approaches, so voting to close as too broad. 1) Impose an interface on init and pass the subclass to the registration method. 2) Use a subclass hook. 3) just have each particle register itself if. 3 seems best right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the easiest way to do this is using `Particle`'s `__subclasses__` method.

You could define `ParticleSystem` like this:

```
class ParticleSystem(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.particles = []

    def create_particle(self, particle_type, location):
        if particle_type in (cls.__name__ for cls in Particle.__subclasses__()):
            p = eval(particle_type)(self)
            p.location = location
            self.particles.append(p)
        else:
            raise TypeError("{} is not a subclass of Particle".format(particle_type))
```

That said, it's often a good idea to avoid having different classes know about each other's inner workings. Does `ParticleSystem` really need to know all the subclasses of `Particle` (better yet - does each particle need to know about the system it's in?)? Or do you just need an easy way to instantiate new `Particle` objects? If you simply need the latter, you could just use a [simple factory method](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html).

Note: using `eval` is generally a bit reckless, but because it is protected by the `in Particle.__subclasses__()` condition, we should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, the `__subclasses__` attribute is exactly what I was seeking for, in that case, the particles will deal with forces, attract and repeal each other, so, is really important for a particle to know its system.